# Changing font size if certain rank?

Tags: php, html, css

so I am trying to figure out a way to change the font size of a user based on their rank. I am not sure if this is done using php or html or some other type of coding but right now I have and I am not sure if I should add an  tag or how it could be done. Thanks for the help

```
<td>
<?php 
    if($r->rank=='120') {
       echo $r->username;
    }
?>
</td>
```

Comment: Just a side note, you should adjust your tags for this question. Java is different than Javascript and I'm assuming that's what you meant

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to add a class to the containing element to the output if the user has a certain rank.

```
<?php
    if ($r->rank > 10) echo "<p class='high-rank'>" . $content . "</p>";
    else echo "<p>" . $content . "</p>";
?>
```

Then, give the class some styling in css.

```
.high-rank {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if($r->rank=='120') {
$fontsize = "25px";
}
if($r->rank=='100') {
$fontsize = "15px";
}
?><

<?php
echo '<p style="font-size:'.$fontsize.'">' . $content . "</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions posted work, but this would be the method I personally would go about doing, as then you can create styles around your ranks, instead of a clusterfuck of names and things like class='high-rank'

PHP/HTML example:

```
<p class='rank rank-<?php echo $r->rank; ?>'><?php echo $r->username; ?></p>
```

CSS examples:

```
p.rank {
  /* basic styles here */
}
p.rank-110 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
p.rank-120 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```